# I need help with the name of this rule

Tags: terminology

I need to prove it for $7$ points. 
 
If $a^x = a^z$ then $x = z$.
What's the name of this rule? 
I need a proof.

Comment: Rule* nvm just correcting

Comment: What type of object is $A$?  Without more context it is false.  Think about powers of one or powers of the identity matrix.

Comment: Yuor claim fails if and only if either $0$ or a root of $1$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Mmm I'm just a 14 years old kid .

Comment: That's not an excuse.  If you are old enough to be asked this question, you should be old enough to answer this question.

Comment: it's just a number and the rule also states that it shouldn't be negative nor zero , I need the name or the proof please please

Comment: You still haven't answered the question in my very first comment... what type of object is $A$?  Is it a real number?  Is it a matrix?  Is it a function?  Is it a pet cat?  Are there any restrictions on it it?  Again, it is false until you have specified further.  $1^5=1^9$ but $5\neq 9$

Comment: Sorry , real number

Comment: More like (1/2)^x = 2^8 solve for x .. that simple

Comment: I need the name or the proof it's extra points just for the research even if we don't know how we've came to that result

Comment: Until you've corrected the statement, I can't give a name to it except "false."  There is no reason to give a name to a false statement.  Once you've corrected the statement, the phrase "monotonicity of the exponential function" should help by noticing that for $A$ a real number strictly greater than $1$ you have $A^x=A^y$ if and only if $1=A^{y-x}$

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a rule, at least as you've presented it.  For example, $1^4 = 1^2$, but $4 \neq 2$.  Similarly, this holds for $0^4 = 0^2$ and $(-1)^4 = (-1)^2$.

However, if $A$ is a positive number with $A \neq 0$ and $A \neq 1$, we have
$$
A^x = A^z \implies \\
\log(A^x) = \log(A^z) \implies\\
x \log(A) = z \log(A) \implies\\
x = z
$$
I don't know of any "name" for this rule.  Perhaps we can call it the "well-definedness of the log base $A$", or "the injectivity of $f(x) = A^x$".

Answer (score 0):

Before this question can be answered, you need to clarify where A is a real number, a 1-D array, or a 2-D array (matrix), etc. This is important because the power of a matrix does not act the same on a 2-D matrix as on a 1-D integer. Linear algebric operators have very specific meaning, therefore you need to be careful when defining your problem. For example, if A were the matrix [[1,2],[1,5]], then A^0=I, A to the zeroth power equals the identity matrix. This is different from a 1-D, real number. 
Let's assume A is matrix. If A is the identity, then, this statement does not hold because I^3=I^9, but 3!=9, and you have proven it not to be true by contradiction. Similarly, if A were the number 1, this would not be true either by contradiction. Hope this helps.